# How to access a instance method of a custom class in ObjC (iOS programming)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pointers, ios4

I'm playing around with the iOS SDK and tried to use a selfmade class within an iPhone app.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface MyPoint
: NSObject {
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
}
- (void) setX:(CGFloat)x_;
- (void) setY:(CGFloat)y_;
- (CGFloat) getX;
- (CGFloat) getY;
- (CGFloat) getDistance;

@end
```

This is the header of my Point class. Now in the app I want to enter 2 numbers (in two different text fields) and then when I press the button "Compute" I call the function getDistance

```
- (IBAction)calcDistance:(id)sender {
  CGFloat x = [fieldx.text doubleValue];
  CGFloat y = [fieldy.text doubleValue];
  [point setX:(x)];
  [point setY:(y)];
  CGFloat test = [point getX];
  CGFloat test2 = [point getY];
  CGFloat result = [point getDistance];
  NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Distance: %f",result];    
  resultLabel.text = resultString;
  [resultString release];
}
```

I was under the impression that

```
[name method]
```

is the way to access member methods of a pointer, but that doesnt do anything, when debugging any of the values that I want to assign in the above manner, nothing changes.

Lastly, the interface of my app:

```
@interface iOS4ViewController : UIViewController {
   UITextField*    fieldx;
   UITextField*    fieldy;
   UILabel*        resultLabel;
   MyPoint* point;
}
```

Hopefully I was clear enough that someone can point out the obvious mistake I'm doing :)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you forget `alloc/init` `point` object?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you may not have allocated an actual instance of `MyPoint`.  Does it work if you try it like this:

```
- (IBAction)calcDistance:(id)sender {
    point = [[MyPoint alloc] init];
    CGFloat x = [fieldx.text doubleValue];
    CGFloat y = [fieldy.text doubleValue];
    [point setX:(x)];
    [point setY:(y)];
    CGFloat test = [point getX];
    CGFloat test2 = [point getY];
    CGFloat result = [point getDistance];
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Distance: %f",result];    
    resultLabel.text = resultString;
    [resultString release];
    [point release];
}
```

As for how to call a method on an instance of a custom class (or any other Object in Objective-C), you are correct, the proper syntax is `[myObjectVarName method]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you alloc `point`?  If an object is nil, calling a method on it will return nil, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you haven't defined those getter/setter methods declared in the header files. If that is the case, you have to either **define them** in the implementation file, or, you can use **declared properties**, to achieve what you need. Create properties in header files like this,

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat x, y;
```

Synthesize it in the implementation file,

```
@synthesize x, y;
```

Synthesizing properties automatically creates the getter and setter method for the properties.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to include the Point.h file in which you are trying to call methods...

Answer (score 0):

First off: thanks for all the help.
It works now that I've called

```
 point = [[MyPoint alloc] init];
```

within the function calcDistance as aroth (and others) suggested.

@EmptyStack, I had the setter and getter defined in the implementation file but thanks for the hint about declared properties.

Cheers!

Comment: perhaps you should  make comments on the answers that helped you, and accept and answer.

Comment: You are right, I should do that!
Seems like I can't though since I created this question as an unregistered User and I don't see any checks near the answers. Do I have to take possession of the question somehow?

Comment: It associated the question with you. You should be able to do whatever